# I dont know where my fault in the script is (python3)

Tags: python-3.x

It should just print if the day or month is wrong, thanky for answering

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpc1t.png)

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` on line 11.

Comment: If you ask a question again, please include the actual code and not an image of it. It makes it a lot easier to copy and paste it so we can reproduce your error.

Comment: Please give us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Instead of posting images, write your code like ```code```

Comment: And remove the line `vv`.

Comment: okay thx, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you embed your code directly into the post to make it easier for people to review.

Here's a code that works :

```
day = (int(input("Enter the day : ")))

month = (int(input("Enter the month : ")))

if day < 1 or day > 31:
    print("Incorrect day value entered!")

elif month > 12 or month < 1:
    print("Incorrect month value entered!")

else :
    print("The month & day entered are valid")
```